# Android Java - Show incoming caller name and number

Tags: java, android

I have implemented my own ConnectionService and creating an new incoming call. The code is currently not showing the caller name - just the number

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public Connection onCreateIncomingConnection(final PhoneAccountHandle connectionManagerPhoneAccount, final ConnectionRequest request) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        NativeTelephonyConnection callConnection = new NativeTelephonyConnection(context);

        var callerName = request.getExtras().getString(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CALL_BACK_NUMBER);
        var callerNumber = request.getExtras().getParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_CALL_ADDRESS);

        callConnection.setConnectionProperties(Connection.CAPABILITY_HOLD | Connection.CAPABILITY_MUTE);
        callConnection.setAddress(request.getAddress(), TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);
        callConnection.setCallerDisplayName(callerName, TelecomManager.PRESENTATION_ALLOWED);

        callConnection.setInitializing();
        callConnection.setActive();
        return callConnection;
    }
```

I can confirm that both the callerName and callerNumber contain strings. Is it because the contact isn't in the phone contacts?

The emulator displays this:
[image: Phone screen]